# Git: how to ignore all target and build subdirectories?

Tags: git

I have a lot of projects organized in tree.

There are a lot of directories "`target`" and "`build`" in random places of the tree, and I want to vanish them all form Git repository ignoring them.

Please tell me what to add to `.gitignore` for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.gitignore** is indeed the way to go here.

The actual content of gitignore file depends on the actual technologies you're working with, build system, ide, etc.

Here is an example of such a **.gitignore** file (relevant for java developers):

```
# Maven
target/

# IntelliJ project files 
*.iml
*.iws
*.ipr
.idea/
.idea

# eclipse project file
.settings/
.classpath
.project

# Binaries
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip
*.war
*.ear
*.sar
*.class

# Misc
*.swp
release.properties
pom.xml.releaseBackup
pom.xml.tag
```

Note the "target/" definition - you can add 'build' folder following the same pattern.

One caveat though: add .gitignore to git (read commit it) before the actual "garbage" files are created (for example before you're running the build tool that creates some stuff in the target directory).

A presence of `.gitignore` file won't really "remove" the already committed files.
I usually tend to commit `.gitignore` right after the initial commit.

If you've already committed some files, remove them first and then commit the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `target/` should be enough.

Make sure to put it in a .gitignore at the root folder of your Git repository.

And check it works (even without committing) with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/target/aFile
```

If it does not (meaning you get an empty output):

```
git rm -r --cached -- path/to/target/aFile
```

Then try again the `git check-ignore` command: you should see a `.gitignore` rule.